# Function keeps returning NaN, tuition calculator

Tags: javascript, function, nan

I can't seem to get my function right.....It's a tuition calculator. At this point the residency and semesters don't matter. It's just credits * credit cost, but it keeps returning NaN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Greendale Community College</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        /* ]]> */
        var numCredits = 0;
        var creditCost = 302;
        var instate = 0;
        var outstate = 0;
        var international = 0;
        var tuitionCost = number;
        function calcTuition(numCredits, creditCost) {
            var tuitionCost = numCredits * creditCost;
            document.write("Your tuition cost is $" + tuitionCost);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><center><font face="impact" font size="200" color="green">Greendale  Community College</font></center></p>
        <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256"/></center>
        <h1><center>Tuition Calculator</center></h1>
        <form name="calculator" action="" method="get">
        <h2>Semester</h2>
        <h3>(choose a semester)</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="semesterFall"/> Fall 2018 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="semesterSpring"/> Spring 2018 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="semesterSummer"/> Summer 2018 <br />
        <h2>Residency</h2>
        <h3>(choose your residency)</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="instate" /> In-State <br />
            <input type="radio" name="outstate" /> Out-of-State <br />
            <input type="radio" name="international" /> International <br />
        <h2>Credits</h2>
        <h3>(enter your number of credits)</h3>
            <input type="text" name="numCredits" size="2" onchange="calcTuition(numCredits, creditCost)"/> Credits <br />
            <input type="button" name="tuition"  onclick="window.alert(calcTuition(numCredits, creditCost))" value="Calculate your Tuition" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At least one of the operands is not a number.

Comment: You're trying to do the calculation when the credits are entered, but the tuition has not been entered yet. You need both values in order to do the function, so don't call `calcTuition` until you have them both.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so where do you mean?  Don't call from where?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at what's going on and it looks like you're trying to call `numCredits` when it is not a valid number. The exact type of it is `$[object HTMLInputElement]`. Addition between an HTMLInputElement and Integer is undefined behavior and as a result the value that you obtain is NaN.

One possible solution is using the `document.getElementbyId` method to return the actual element and then you can perform any operation on them.

PS: You should try and debug your own functions, you mentioned you're new to this but it would be great to set up some print statements or use an interactive debugger to see exactly where the problem is occurring. This way you can troubleshoot it and understand the problem at the same time.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio, how do I debug?

Comment: This should probably be a different question, but do your research first before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var c_amount = 302;
    function calcu_Tuition(Credits, c_amount) {
    //var Credits 
    var Credits = document.getElementById("Credits").value //it will get the value of Credits text box and be transfer to Credits variable.

    var tuition = 0;
        var tuition = Credits * c_amount;
        document.write("Your tuition cost is $" + tuition);
    }

</script>

<body>
    <h2>Credits</h2>
    <h3>(enter your number of credits)</h3> 
        <input type="text" id="Credits" size="2" onchange="calcu_Tuition(Credits, c_amount)"/> Credits <br>
        <button id="tuition"  onclick="calcu_Tuition(c_amount)">Calculate your Tuition"</button>
        </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what you changed and why. It's not clear to me what you're trying to say.